# Use OR in vlookup Table Array

Tags: excel, vlookup

Is it possible to write a vlookup to point to one worksheet or another?

I have a master spreadsheet that points to a weekly spreadsheet via vlookup. Sometimes the sheet name will be called "SKU" and other times "Sales by sku".

The sheet name is the only part that changes. The cell ranges i point to will be the same for both circumstances.

Can i write a vlookup to point to one sheet if not point to the other?

My current vlookup:

`=VLOOKUP(A2,'...OTC\2016\Reports Sent\[Current BSL, Branch Stock, Whouse Stock, On Order.xls]SKU'!$D$1:$G$65536,4,FALSE)`

I want something like:

[Current BSL, Branch Stock, Whouse Stock, On Order.xls]SKU **OR** Sales by sku'!$D$1:$G$65536,4,FALSE)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) sould be enough in this case:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'...OTC\2016\Reports Sent\[Current BSL, Branch Stock, Whouse Stock, On Order.xls]Sales by sku'!$D$1:$G$65536,4,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A2,'...OTC\2016\Reports Sent\[Current BSL, Branch Stock, Whouse Stock, On Order.xls]SKU'!$D$1:$G$65536,4,FALSE))
```

**EDIT**

Merged with `INDIRECT` it should look like this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'...OTC\2016\Reports Sent\[Current BSL, Branch Stock, Whouse Stock, On Order.xls]Sales by sku'!$D$1:$G$65536",1),4,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'...OTC\2016\Reports Sent\[Current BSL, Branch Stock, Whouse Stock, On Order.xls]SKU'!$D$1:$G$65536",1),4,FALSE))
```

Comment: I've tried this and it sort of works. The problem is that the 1st vlookup works, but 2nd vlookup/IFERROR condition does not do anything. It seems like it will do condition 1 and that's it; it doesn't move onto condition 2. If that makes sense.

Comment: the second condition will only be executed if the first expression returns an error, which should be the case if the sheet doesn't exist

Comment: That is correct. That is what we are expecting the formula to do. However, the cell does not update unless i open & close the spreadsheet the vlookup is pointing to. Then the vlookup data will update. When it does, within the vlookup formula, the sheet that it cannot find will be replaced with `#REF'!`

Comment: Example code: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'...2016\[Current BSL, Branch Stock, Whouse Stock, On Order.xls]Sales by SKU'!$D$1:$G$65536,4,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A2,'...2016\[Current BSL, Branch Stock, Whouse Stock, On Order.xls]#REF'!$D$1:$G$65536,4,FALSE))`

Comment: try to merge it in an `INDIRECT`, then the formula should not change anything to `#REF`

Comment: Consider me an absolute noob. How do I merge `INDIRECT` correctly? Do i nest the current formula inside `INDIRECT()`? How should it look?

Comment: pls see my EDIT part of the answer ;)

Comment: I tried your edited code. It works, however, with `INDIRECT` i need to open and close the referenced workbook in order to update the cell value.

Comment: it tries to connect to the file and if that fails, it will force you to show the "new" destination... I'm not sure how to solve that without VBA :/

Comment: Hey you've helped me a great deal. I appreciate it. I think I know what to do from here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Indirect(If(<logic here>,"'...OTC\2016\Reports Sent\[Current BSL, Branch Stock, Whouse Stock, On Order.xls]SKU'!$D$1:$G$65536","second address")`

Comment: I honestly have not used `INDIRECT` before. I'm not sure what I am looking at here. Nor do I know what to expect the result to be.

Comment: [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) is the only way to refer to a cell/range having the path as string like `=INDIRECT("A"&B1)` will show the value of A5 if B1 is 5 (or A10 if B1 is 10) :)